# Unable to refresh existing singleton bean in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I have a configuration defined in my spring boot applocation as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RuleEngineConfiguration {

  private final DatabaseRuleLoader databaseRuleLoader;

  public RuleEngineConfiguration(
      DatabaseRuleLoader databaseRuleLoader) {
    this.databaseRuleLoader = databaseRuleLoader;
  }

  @Bean
  public RuleEngineManager ruleEngine() {
    return RuleEngineManagerFactory.getRuleEngineManager(this.databaseRuleLoader);
  }
```

Now I would like to refresh `RuleEngineManager` bean in my spring boot application on creating/update of a row in a given table in DB with refresh function as defined below:

```
public void refresh() {
    databaseRuleLoader.refresh(); <---THIS RELOADS ROWS FROM DB
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext
        .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    RuleEngineManager ruleEngineManager = RuleEngineManagerFactory
        .getRuleEngineManager(databaseRuleLoader);
    registry.removeBeanDefinition("ruleEngine");
    ((SingletonBeanRegistry) registry).registerSingleton("ruleEngine", ruleEngineManager);
  }
```

And in my application, where I need `RuleEngineManager` bean, I am getting the bean as follows:

```
((RuleEngineManager) applicationContext.getBean("ruleEngine"))
```

Even though the refresh function is getting executed every time, I am creating/updating any rows in DB, but, I am not seeing any changes. It seems the existing `RuleEnginemanager` bean is getting injected as a dependency. I am not able to figure out what I am missing here.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: I mean, this is not a solution, but what about creating a factory for that object, and using DI to inject the factory, so that when you want the object, you go like `factory.generate()` and you have a new fresh object? (and you can implement on your own a lazy loading / cache / refresh logic)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia thanks for your response. I am sorry, I could not understand much. Could you please briefly elaborate by giving a code snippet from which I can get an idea?

Answer (score 0):

What I was suggesting is to use a factory (design pattern)... for example in this way:

```
// you already have this class
public class RuleEngineManagerFactory{ 
   private DatabaseRuleLoader databaseRuleLoader;
   private RuleEngineManager ruleEngineManager;
   public RuleEngineManagerFactory(DatabaseRuleLoader databaseRuleLoader) {
     this.databaseRuleLoader = databaseRuleLoader;
   }
   public RuleEngineManager getRuleEngineManager(){
     if(this.ruleEngineManager == null){
         ruleEngineManager = new RuleEngineManager(this.databaseRuleLoader);
     }
     return this.ruleEngineManager;
   }
   public void refresh(){
      ruleEngineManager = new RuleEngineManager(this.databaseRuleLoader);
   }
}
```

In this way, you will inject `RuleEngineManagerFactory` wherever you need, and you can refresh the `RuleEngineManager`... so you will have to have a singleton for the factory of the manager,  and not for the manager itself